# Reinterpret template type at compile time

Tags: c++, tuples, variadic-templates, c++14

I would like to create a class,  that basically contains a private attribut :

```
template<typename TA, typename T2, ... Tn> // Use something like <typename... Tn> ?
class A
{
    public:
    A(){};
    ~A(){};

    std::tuple<std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<T1>>, std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<T2>>, ...> t;
};
```

but I would like to be able to write something simple like :

```
A<int, double, std::string> a;
```

and it automatically builds the corresponding :

```
std::tuple<std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<int>>, std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<double>>, std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<std::string>>> t;
```

(for any number of arguments in tuple)

So I just want to transform any T to std::reference_wrapper< T > and pass it to the tuple.
How can I do that ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just expand the pack:

```
template <typename ...Args>
struct Foo
{
    std::tuple<std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<Args>>...> t;
};
```

Comment: wahoo, I did not know we could unpack this way, this so convenient! Thank you very much!